# Intern integration with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, intern

**ENVIRONMENT**

We are currently using 2 Chutzpah packages ([this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0) and [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe)) in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 to enable us to execute individual Jasmine unit tests (with Chutzpah context menu "Open in Browser") against an angular application we are developing.

We currently have to use Chrome developer tools to set breakpoints and debug the unit tests.

The current Jenkins build is running Moq Unit Tests against the C# application code and cross-browser Selenium tests with SauceLabs.

The next step for the JS tests is to execute them as part of our Jenkins build along with the other tests.

To achieve this the best tool currently is [Intern](http://theintern.io).

**OUR REQUIREMENTS**

1. Execute JS Tests and calculate coverage as part of the Jenkins Build
   on SauceLabs.
2. Execute and step through (debug) JS Unit Tests

Regarding 1, I can see from the Intern [example](https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples/tree/master/angularjs-example) that we will probably have to (and can) rewrite our tests for Intern to get them to execute on Jenkins and SauceLabs.

Regarding 2, the point of this post:

**MY QUESTIONS**

- Can tests written in the manner of the Intern example be debugged in chrome with developer tools?
- Is there a need for a Chutzpah-like tool to integrate Visual Studio
  with Intern?  (Is [this](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) the analogous tool?)